# Batch script to return the path of a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a code which will display the path of a file I define. For example I have two files

1. D:\Test\ExecuteScript.bat
2. D:\document.txt

I wish to define the file name "document.txt" in my script and will return "D:\Test\ExecuteScript.bat". I have also tried the following code:

> for /r %%x in (*document.txt) do echo "%%x"

**However**, this only work if the document.txt is inside a folder while the ExecuteScript.bat is outside the folder, for exmaple:

1. D:\ExecuteScript.bat
2. D:\Test\document.txt

I have searched many online solution but many of which requires me to put C:\ at the front of the code which I do not want. Many thanks in advance and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: `for /R "D:\" %%x in ("*document.txt") do echo "%%~x"`; if you are working on the same drive: `for /R "\" %%x in ("*document.txt") do echo "%%~x"` is sufficient; or do you want to search in *all* drives?

Comment: `for /r "d:\tests" %%x in ("*document.txt") do echo "%%x"`  ?

Comment: @aschipfl do you have the code that will search in all drives?

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44695135) below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell [`for /R`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) where to start searching for files, simply state the path behind `/R`:

```cmd
for /R "D:\" %%x in ("*document.txt") do echo "%%~x"
```

If you are working on the same drive as you search, the following is sufficient:

```cmd
for /R "\" %%x in ("*document.txt") do echo "%%~x"
```

Here is an excerpt from the help of `for` appearing when you type `for /?`:

> ```cmd
> FOR /R [[drive:]path] %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]
>
>     Walks the directory tree rooted at [drive:]path, executing the FOR
>     statement in each directory of the tree.  If no directory
>     specification is specified after /R then the current directory is
>     assumed.  If set is just a single period (.) character then it
>     will just enumerate the directory tree.
> ```

---

In case you want to search in *all* drives, you could do the following:

```cmd
rem // Loop through all drive letters:
for %%d in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
    rem // Temporarily try to change to root of current drive:
    pushd "%%d:\" 2> nul && (
        rem // Drive found, so search it for matching files:
        for /R %%x in ("*document.txt") do echo "%%~x"
        popd
    )
)
```